# Open close panel by Id material accordion

Tags: angular, angular-material, accordion

Am I able to control, hence open/close individual panels by an assigned Id using the Material accordion, https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview#accordion.

Comment: can you share some code, what you have tried so far and also provide a minimal `stackblitz.com` example of your scenario.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by *`Open close panel by Id material accordion`*

Comment: I meant dynamically creating the accordion in the code-behind, whilst assigning a unique id to each header. Hence enabling the ability to open and close individual panels programatically. I believe the ng-bootstrap accordion is capable of this, however I would like to stick to the MatAccordion, rather than install/use multiple component libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I tried a solution, [StackBlitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-open-close-panel-by-button-material-accordion).

I've not find a way to use an ID for panel control, but you can use a variable.
Here, I use activePanel which takes a value depending on the event (1 for the button_1, 2 for the button_2, ...).

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="activePanel = 1">Open 1</button>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="activePanel = 2">Open 2</button>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="activePanel = 3">Open 3</button>
```

In your panel you use the function ngOnChanges which will open the panel according to your variable.

```
ngOnChanges() {
    if(this.panelState2 == 2) {this.panelState = true;}
    else {this.panelState = false;}
}
```

The panelState variable is a boolean to open or close your panel with [expanded].

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="panelState">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      Title Panel
    </mat-panel-title>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <p>Accedat huc suavitas quaedam oportet sermonum atque morum,...</p>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

I hope this will help you.

DEMO:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, however my ultimate goal is to have nested accordions, hence activate 'accordion_1', then activate a nested accordion 'accordion_1_2', then  activate nested accordion on 2nd level > 'accordion_1_2_1', and so on. This is the reason i requested by Id, hence a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I tried another solution, [StackBlitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-open-close-panel-by-id-material-accordion).

This time I managed to use an ID for panel control.
Here, I use a unique ID on each mat-expansion-panel (`#first` for the panel_1, `#second` for the panel_2, ...).

```
<mat-accordion multi="true">
  <mat-expansion-panel #first></mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel #second></mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel #third></mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

I also used buttons to control these panels without interacting with them.

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="changeState1()">ON/OFF Panel_1</button>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="changeState2()">ON/OFF Panel_2</button>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="changeState3()">ON/OFF Panel_3</button>
```

In your TypeScript code, you use @ViewChild to retrieve the panel ID so you can control it.

```
@ViewChild('first') first: MatExpansionPanel;
@ViewChild('second') second: MatExpansionPanel;
@ViewChild('third') third: MatExpansionPanel;
```

Then, I created functions to open one to close the mat-expansion-panel according to its ID and according to its state.

```
changeState1() {
  if(this.first.expanded){
    this.first.close();
  } else {
    this.first.open();
  }
}

changeState2() {...}
```

PS: `<mat-accordion multi="true">` allows multiple panels to open simultaneously.

DEMO:

[image]

Comment: Can you do that with viewchildren when the number of accordions is not defined?